# Match column of one file to column of another using awk when second file column contains commas

Tags: awk, grep, delimiter

I have two files - one is a large file containing variants in genes, with multiple columns separated by tab. The column containing the gene names may contain a single name, or multiple names separated by commas (gene name in example is SAMD11 and NOC2L):

```
1   874816  874816  -   T   rs200996316 SAMD11  exonic  ENSG00000187634 frameshift insertion
1   878331  878331  C   T   rs148327885 SAMD11  exonic  ENSG00000187634 nonsynonymous SNV
1   879676  879676  G   A   rs6605067   NOC2L,SAMD11    UTR3    ENSG00000187634,ENSG00000188976
1   879687  879687  T   C   rs2839  NOC2L,SAMD11    UTR3    ENSG00000187634,ENSG00000188976
1   881918  881918  G   A   rs35471880  NOC2L   exonic  ENSG00000188976 nonsynonymous SNV
1   888659  888659  T   C   rs3748597   NOC2L   exonic  ENSG00000188976 nonsynonymous SNV
```

The second file is a single column list of gene names, such as this:

```
EVC2
SAMD11
COMT
```

I want to match the gene names in the second file with those in the first file. I am currently using awk:

```
awk -F $'\t' 'BEGIN { while(getline <"secondfile.txt") gene[$0]=1; } gene[$7]' firstfile.txt > newfile.txt
```

However, this only prints exact matches so doesn't print the lines with NOC2L,SAMD11. From the above example, the expected output would be the first four lines of the first file:

```
1   874816  874816  -   T   rs200996316 SAMD11  exonic  ENSG00000187634 frameshift insertion
1   878331  878331  C   T   rs148327885 SAMD11  exonic  ENSG00000187634 nonsynonymous SNV
1   879676  879676  G   A   rs6605067   NOC2L,SAMD11    UTR3    ENSG00000187634,ENSG00000188976
1   879687  879687  T   C   rs2839  NOC2L,SAMD11    UTR3    ENSG00000187634,ENSG00000188976
```

I want it to still do exact matches, as some of the gene names can be similar - eg there may be a gene called SAMD1, and if I did a fuzzy match for that then I would get SAMD1, SAMD11 and so on. So I need something that does an exact match but ignores the comma in the gene name column, or treats it as a field delimiter or similar.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks, have done so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR { genes[$0]; next }
{
    split($7,a,/,/)
    for (i in a) {
        if (a[i] in genes) {
            print
            next
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk secondfile.txt firstfile.txt
1   874816  874816  -   T   rs200996316 SAMD11  exonic  ENSG00000187634 frameshift insertion
1   878331  878331  C   T   rs148327885 SAMD11  exonic  ENSG00000187634 nonsynonymous SNV
1   879676  879676  G   A   rs6605067   NOC2L,SAMD11    UTR3    ENSG00000187634,ENSG00000188976
1   879687  879687  T   C   rs2839  NOC2L,SAMD11    UTR3    ENSG00000187634,ENSG00000188976
```

This would also work:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR { genes[$0]; next }
{
    for (gene in genes) {
        if ($7 ~ "(^|,)"gene"(,|$)") {
            print
            next
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works! Can I ask what the 'a' in the split is doing?

Comment: That's the name the the array that `split()` is populating. man awk and look up `split()`. I'm going to post a couple of alternatives for you too - might be a good intro to awk for you to see some different ways of tackling the problem. Note - none of them involves `getline`!